# Version control, file history and versioning for Microsoft Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, version-control

What Software allows me to **go into the folder properties** and **enable file versioning** / a file history, so that any overwrite can be undone?

Windows Vista and beyond do provide simple versioning through restore points, and is not what I am looking for.

Thanks,

Comment: You are looking for `Volume Shadow Copy`: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-to-enable-volume-shadow-copy-in-windows-7/faaf7490-d929-47a6-a12f-1bf100db66e5

Comment: Thanks. But as far as I can tell, `Volume Shadow Copy` is the service behind the System Point backup/restore frontend. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @LoSauer: Are you looking for [Previous](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions) [Versions](http://www.howtogeek.com/56891/use-windows-7s-previous-versions-to-go-back-in-time-and-save-your-files/) perhaps?